# Python-Sync folders between Windows Server and Ubuntu on same network

Tags: python, mysql, node.js, linux, windows-server-2012

I want a Python script that syncs an **images** folder stored on my Windows Server 2012 with an **images** folder stored on my Ubuntu. They're on same network, so I think I just need the Windows Server's ip address to communicate with it.

**Windows path to folder:** C:\inetpub\wwwroot\images

**Ubuntu path to folder**: /nodeGit/code/assets/images

The images on the Windows server will already have an entry on my SQL database (which is on my Ubuntu server) with the correct filename stored under **imagePath**. When I pull the images over from Windows, I only want the images whose **uploaded** values are **0**. After moving them, their **uploaded** value should change to **1**. (ignore "imageApproved")

[image]

Comment: What have to tried so far?

Comment: At first I couldn't find anything helpful, but I recently found this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python and I'm going to try to download the images using their URL with that. I've downloaded mySQLdb and established a connection to my database in a script